# Can't shoot fire ball twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm making a game similar to Space Invaders just with Poke'mon. In the game, the player (Charmeleon) should shoot fire balls when hitting the Space key (one fire ball for each press). The problem is when I hit the Space key, the player shoots all of the fire balls at the same time after only one press. How can I fix it? I will give the game free to the one who will solve my problem after I will finish. Here is my code:

```
if (ableToFire == true)
    {
        GameObject Flame = GameObject.Find("Fire");

        if (usedFire == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Debug.Log("Fire");

                Flame.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
                Flame.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 175);

                usedFire++;

                Debug.Log("You used fire " + usedFire + " times");
            }
        }


        GameObject Flame2 = GameObject.Find("Fire 2");

        if (usedFire == 1)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Debug.Log("Fire");

                Flame2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
                Flame2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 175);

                usedFire++;

                Debug.Log("You used fire " + usedFire + " times");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The player shoots all of the fire balls at the same time after only
> one press.

We can see more clearly why that happens if we inspect the flow of your code. First we check if the player is able to fire if he is, we then additional check if the `usedFire` integers is 0 or 1.

The problem is right now that after going into the `usedFire == 0` part of your code we increase the `usedFire` variable, then we leave the function and after that we check if the `usedFire` variable is 1. Which it is, because we just increased it.

So now the second part of the code get's called again increasing the `usedFire` variable to 3. Reuslting in neihter part of the code called and so not resulting in any more fireballs.

```cs
if (ableToFire != true || !Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    // If the player can't fire or hasn't pressed space, skip the rest of the code.
    return;
}

if (usedFire == 0) {   
    Flame.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
    Flame.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 175);

    usedFire++;
    Debug.Log("You used fire " + usedFire + " times");
}
else if(usedFire == 1) {
    Flame2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
    Flame2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 175);

    usedFire++;
    Debug.Log("You used fire " + usedFire + " times");

    // Reset usedFire so we can use it again.
    usedFire = 0;
}
```

I would also advise you to move both `GameObject.Find()` calls into the `Start()` Method, because searching 2 GameObject each frame is really taxing to the games performance.

```cs
GameObject Flame;
GameObject Flame2;

private void Start() {
    Flame = GameObject.Find("Fire");
    Flame2 = GameObject.Find("Fire 2");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I had a little problem you couldn't predict but I fixed it so you are my favorite person now, Mathew. After I finish the game, I will send it to you free. (It will be free to everyone but who cares)

Comment: I'll sure try it, seems like it's interesting :D

Comment: Hi, I finally finished the game. I promised you I will send you the game so here it is. It's my first game: https://baryo.itch.io/pokemon-invaders

Comment: I'll save it and play it once I'm home :P

Comment: I would advise you to build a WebGL build tough, you'll have much more people play your game if they can do so in their browser.